# How to filter the records with sub-children

Tags: c#, linq, multidimensional-array, filtering

I want to filter products by `subCategories`.

This is my JSON for products:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Adidas Quick Force",
    "price": 3500.00,
    "pictureUrl": "/adidas_shoe-1.png",
    "category": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "FootBall",
        "subCategories": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "FootBall Boots"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "FootBalls"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I can filter by `Category` by this method:

```cs
public static IQueryable<Product> FilterCategory(this IQueryable<Product> products, string name)
{
    if (name != null)
    {
        return products.Where(e => (e.Category.Name == name) );
    }
    return products;
}
```

I tried this but it gives an error:

```cs
public static IQueryable<Product> FilterCategory(this IQueryable<Product> products, string name)
{
    if (name != null)
    {
        return products.Where(e => (e.Category.subCategories.Name == name) ); // error is here
    }
    return products;
}
```

Comment: Please specify the error.

Comment: `subCategories` is an array/collection. Do arrays or collections have a `Name` property? No, they don't, so how could you filter by one? If the items in that array/collection have such a property then that's what you need to filter against, but you haven't explained how you actually want to filter. Do all the items have to match that name? Any of the items? Ata least two of the items? Put some thought into the logic and provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `SubCategories` is an array/list, you can't directly access the `Name` property.

Instead, you can look for [`.Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-7.0) with a predicate to filter the product containing the nested object with matching name in the `subCategories` array.

```cs
return products.Where(e => e.Category.subCategories.Any(x => x.Name == name));
```